# Capturing on loopback device on Ubuntu LTS: 15 Mbit of traffic and "x dropped packets"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcpdump, loopback

I am trying to capture about 15 Mbit of traffic on the loopback device on Ubuntu LTS using tcpdump, and I am seeing dropped packets.

The CPU is a freaking i7, and i have yet to see CPU usage go above 15% during the measurements i am trying to run. Load is negligible...

The capture is written to a file using `-w`.

I have tried the following (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7018039/55267 ):

- Set `/proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog` and
  `/proc/sys/net/core/netdev_budget` to arbitarily high values. No effect.
- `-nn` No effect
- Tried changing `txqueuelen` of `lo`. No effect.
- Tried using gulp. No effect.

  - gulp instructed me to:

    - echo 4194304 >  /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
    - echo 4194304 >  /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
    - No effect....

Is there something special about the loopback device in regard to lossless captures? How can I do a lossless capture on lo?

Comment: Are you sure you can write fast enough? What's the iowait like?

Comment: When you say that CPU usage is not "above 15%", is that for the entire system or a limit per-core? Depending on where you're looking, 15% could be a single core of a HT quad-core pegged.

Comment: @TomO'Connor I looked using `iostat -x 1`, and it never went above 3%.

Comment: @chrylis Entire system. Actually tcpdump is running niced to -20. (Everything else has priority of -10 or more.)

Comment: @TomO'Connor ALso, I have tried gulp which is supposed to help with write speed issues. It keeps a 100 Mb ringbuffer in memory by default.

Comment: And there are no any funky iptables rules throttling traffic to loopback interface?

Comment: @JannePikkarainen Hm, actually I do use netem to delay some traffic.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen Non-delayed traffic is also getting lost. I will try getting rid of all tc stuff to see if it helps.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen: Got rid of the throttling. No effect, still losing packets. (`tc filter show dev lo` outputs nothing now, and `sudo iptables --list` shows no rules)

Comment: Oh well, that was worth a shot anyway. :)

Comment: Yeah, thx for it. :)

Comment: Want a real challenge? Try the same thing again with a realtime kernel, and renice the process to realtime priorities..

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel

Comment: Why would that be a real challenge?